# Writing a hybrid MPI/OpenACC program

Tags: c, cuda, mpi, openacc

I am trying to write a hybrid MPI/OpenACC code, where the code needs to do 8 different jobs (in this case 8 different sweeps). These 8 jobs are divided to [1-8] processes/nodes using MPI and the calculations that needs to be done within the 8 jobs are parallelized using OpenACC.

After each process is done with its calculations, I reduce the solution and pass the minimum to the process 0 which is the final solution.

Below is a MCVE of the full code (test.c) that produces a .txt output file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define min(a,b) (a > b) ? b : a
#define max(a,b) (a < b) ? b : a

#define NPES 8 // max number of PEs allowed
#define DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION   -1
#define DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE   INFINITY
#define DEFAULT_INTERIOR_DISTANCE 90000

typedef struct {
  int order;
  int firstLevel, lastLevel, level;
  int xDim, yDim, zDim;
  int xSweepOff, ySweepOff, zSweepOff;
  double dx, dy, dz;
} SweepInfo;

typedef struct {
  double   dx, dy, dz;
  int * location;
  double * distance;
} Phi;

typedef struct {
  int x, y, z;
} Grid3D;



void calc_dist_field( Phi * p, int totalNodes );
void write_to_file(double * dist);
static SweepInfo make_sweepInfo( Phi * p, int my_rank );
static void fast_sweep( Phi * p, SweepInfo * s );
static double solveEikonal(Phi * p, int index, int max_x, int max_y);
static void update_distance(Phi * p, int totalNodes);
static void set_distance_negative_inside(Phi * p, int totalNodes);
static void adjust_boundary( Phi * p );


// public method declarations
Grid3D make_grid3D(int x, int y, int z);
void vti_get_dimensions(FILE *vti, double *d);
void vti_get_data(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g);

// private method declarations
static void move_file_pointer(FILE *file_ptr, int lineNumber, int r);
static void get_location(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, Grid3D g);
static void get_distance(FILE *vti, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g);

static int npes;          // Number of PEs
static int my_rank;       // Rank of the PE
static char * fileName;
static char * outfileName;

static int NX, NY, NZ, totalNodes;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // MPI startup routine
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &npes);

  fileName    = argv[1];
  outfileName = argv[2];
  FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  double dims[6];
  vti_get_dimensions(f, dims);
  NX = dims[0] + 3;
  NY = dims[1] + 3;
  NZ = dims[2] + 3;

  totalNodes = NX * NY * NZ;
  Phi *p = (Phi *) malloc(sizeof(Phi));
  p->location = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * totalNodes);
  p->distance = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * totalNodes);

  p->dx = dims[3]; p->dy = dims[4]; p->dz = dims[5];

  vti_get_data( f, p->location, DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION,
                   p->distance, DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE,
                make_grid3D(NX, NY, NZ));


  update_distance(p, totalNodes);

  calc_dist_field(p, totalNodes);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

void calc_dist_field( Phi * p, int totalNodes ) {

  int sweepNumber = my_rank + 1;
  double * tmp_dist;

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if(my_rank == 0){
    tmp_dist = (double *) malloc( totalNodes * sizeof(double) );
  }

  // sn represents the sweep number
  for( int sn = sweepNumber; sn <= NPES; sn += npes) {
    SweepInfo s = make_sweepInfo(p, sn);

    printf("PE: [%d] - performing sweep number ..... [%d/%d]\n", my_rank, sn, NPES);

    fast_sweep(p, &s);

    printf("PE: [%d] - completed sweep number ...... [%d/%d]\n", my_rank, sn, NPES);

  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  #pragma acc update host(p->distance[0:totalNodes])
  MPI_Reduce(p->distance, tmp_dist, totalNodes, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if( my_rank == 0 ) {
    free( p->distance );
    p->distance = tmp_dist;
    set_distance_negative_inside(p, totalNodes);
    adjust_boundary(p);
    write_to_file(p->distance);
    printf("%s file created\n", outfileName);
  }

}

static void update_distance(Phi * p, int totalNodes) {

  int    *l = &p->location[0];
  double *d = &p->distance[0];

  for(int i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    if(*l != DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION && *d != DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE ) {
      *d = (*l == 1 && *d == INFINITY) ? -1 : (*d > 0.0 || *d < 0.0) ? *d : DEFAULT_INTERIOR_DISTANCE;
    }
    l++; d++;
  }

}



void write_to_file(double * dist) {

  int x = NX;
  int y = NY;
  int z = NZ;
  char fname[255];
  sprintf(fname, "%s.txt", outfileName);
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "w");

  int i,j,k;
  double *t = &dist[0];
  for(i = 0; i < z; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < x; k++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%f  ", *(t++));
      }
      fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }

}


static SweepInfo make_sweepInfo( Phi * p, int my_rank ) {
  SweepInfo s;

  s.order      = my_rank;
  s.firstLevel = 3;
  s.lastLevel  = (NX + NY + NZ) - 6;

  s.xDim = NX-2; s.dx = p->dx;
  s.yDim = NY-2; s.dy = p->dy;
  s.zDim = NZ-2; s.dz = p->dz;

  s.xSweepOff = (s.order == 4 || s.order == 8 ) ? s.xDim + 1 : 0;
  s.ySweepOff = (s.order == 2 || s.order == 6 ) ? s.yDim + 1 : 0;
  s.zSweepOff = (s.order == 3 || s.order == 7 ) ? s.zDim + 1 : 0;

  return s;
}

static void fast_sweep( Phi * p, SweepInfo * s ) {

  int start, end, incr;

  start = ( s->order == 2 || s->order == 5 || s->order == 7 || s->order == 8 ) ? s->lastLevel : s->firstLevel;

  if ( start == s->firstLevel ) {
    end  = s->lastLevel + 1;
    incr = 1;
  }
  else {
    end  = s->firstLevel - 1;
    incr = 0;
  }

  int max_x  = s->xDim + 2;
  int max_y  = s->yDim + 2;
  int max_xy = max_x * max_y;

  #pragma acc data create(p[0:1]) copy(p->distance[0:totalNodes])
  for(int level = start; level != end; level = (incr) ? level+1 : level-1) {
    // s - start, e - end
    int xs, xe, ys, ye;

    xs = max(1, level-(s->yDim + s->zDim))    , ys = max(1,level-(s->xDim + s->zDim));
    xe = min(s->xDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1)), ye = min(s->yDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1));

    int x, y, z, i, j, k, index;
    #pragma acc parallel
    {
      #pragma acc loop independent
      for(x = xs; x <= xe; x++) {
        #pragma acc loop independent
        for(y = ys; y <= ye; y++) {
          z = level - (x+y);
          if(z > 0 && z <= NZ-2) {
            i = abs(z-s->zSweepOff);
            j = abs(y-s->ySweepOff);
            k = abs(x-s->xSweepOff);
            index = i * max_xy + j * max_x + k;
            p->distance[index] = solveEikonal(p, index, NX, NY);
          }
        }
      } // end of acc parallel
    }
  }
}

#pragma acc routine seq
static double solveEikonal(Phi * p, int index, int max_x, int max_y) {

  int max_xy = max_x * max_y;

  double dist_new = 0;
  double dist_old = p->distance[index];

  double dx = p->dx, dy = p->dy, dz = p->dz;
  double minX = min(p->distance[index-1], p->distance[index+1]);
  double minY = min(p->distance[abs(index-max_x)], p->distance[abs(index+max_x)]);
  double minZ = min(p->distance[abs(index-max_xy)],p->distance[abs(index+max_xy)]);

  double m[] = { minX, minY, minZ} ;
  double d[] = { dx, dy, dz};

  // sort the mins 
  for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3-i; j++) {
      if(m[j] > m[j+1]) {
        double tmp_m = m[j];
        double tmp_d = d[j];
        m[j] = m[j+1]; d[j] = d[j+1];
        m[j+1] = tmp_m; d[j+1] = tmp_d;
      }
    }
  }

  // simplifying the variables
  double m_0 = m[0], m_1 = m[1], m_2 = m[2];
  double d_0 = d[0], d_1 = d[1], d_2 = d[2]; 
  double m2_0 = m_0 * m_0, m2_1 = m_1 * m_1, m2_2 = m_2 * m_2;
  double d2_0 = d_0 * d_0, d2_1 = d_1 * d_1, d2_2 = d_2 * d_2;

  dist_new = m_0 + d_0;
  if(dist_new > m_1) {

    double s = sqrt(- m2_0 + 2 * m_0 * m_1 - m2_1 + d2_0 + d2_1); 
    dist_new = ( m_1 * d2_0 + m_0 * d2_1 + d_0 * d_1 * s) / (d2_0 + d2_1);

    if(dist_new > m_2) {

      double a = sqrt(- m2_0 * d2_1 - m2_0 * d2_2 + 2 * m_0 * m_1 * d2_2
                      - m2_1 * d2_0 - m2_1 * d2_2 + 2 * m_0 * m_2 * d2_1
                      - m2_2 * d2_0 - m2_2 * d2_1 + 2 * m_1 * m_2 * d2_0
                      + d2_0 * d2_1 + d2_0 * d2_2 + d2_1 * d2_2);

      dist_new = (m_2 * d2_0 * d2_1 + m_1 * d2_0 * d2_2 + m_0 * d2_1 * d2_2 + d_0 * d_1 * d_2 * a) /
                  (d2_0 * d2_1 + d2_0 * d2_2 + d2_1 * d2_2);
    }
  }

  return min(dist_old, dist_new);
}



static void set_distance_negative_inside(Phi * p, int totalNodes) {

  int    *l = &p->location[0];
  double *d = &p->distance[0];

  for(int i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    if(*l != DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION && *d != DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE ) {
      if( *l == 1) *d = -1;
    }
    l++; d++;
  }

}

static void adjust_boundary( Phi * p ) {

  int x, y, z, xy, i, j, k;
  x  = NX;
  y  = NY;
  z  = NZ;
  xy = x * y;

  for(i = 0; i < z; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < x; k++){
        int I = i, J = j, K = k;
        I = (i == z-1) ? I-1 : (!i) ? I+1 : I;
        J = (j == y-1) ? J-1 : (!j) ? J+1 : J;
        K = (k == x-1) ? K-1 : (!k) ? K+1 : K;
        if( i != I || j != J || k != K) {
            int l_index = i * xy + j * x + k;
            int r_index = I * xy + J * x + K;
            p->distance[l_index] = p->distance[r_index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



/**************** vti_parser ********************************/

static void move_file_pointer(FILE *file_ptr, int lineNumber, int r) {
    char tmpStr[512];
    if(r) rewind(file_ptr);
    while (lineNumber > 0){
        fgets (tmpStr, 511, file_ptr);
        lineNumber--;
    }
}

void vti_get_dimensions(FILE *vti, double *d) {
    char tmpStr[512];
    rewind(vti);
    while (1) {
        fgets (tmpStr, 511, vti);
        if ( strstr(tmpStr, "ImageData WholeExtent") ) {
            sscanf(tmpStr, "    <ImageData WholeExtent=\"0 %lf 0 %lf 0 %lf\" Spacing=\"%lf %lf %lf\">",
                    &d[0], &d[1], &d[2], &d[3], &d[4], &d[5]);
            break;
        }
    }
}


void vti_get_data(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g) {

    // move the file pointer to
    // line 6 from beginning
    move_file_pointer(vti, 6, 1);

    get_location(vti, l, b_l, g);

    // move the file pointer 2 lines
    // forward from its last position
    move_file_pointer(vti, 2, 0);

    get_distance(vti, d, b_d, g);

}

static void get_location(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, Grid3D g) {
    int i, j, k, *t = &l[0];
    for (i = 0; i < g.z; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < g.y; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < g.x; k++) {
                // Border
                if (k == 0 || k == g.x-1 || j == 0 || j == g.y-1 || i == 0 || i == g.z-1 ) {
                    *(t++) = b_l;
                }
                else{ // Interior
                    fscanf(vti, "%d ", t++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



static void get_distance(FILE *vti, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g) {
    int i, j, k;
    double *t = &d[0];
    for (i = 0; i < g.z; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < g.y; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < g.x; k++) {
                // Border distance
                if (k == 0 || k == g.x-1 || j == 0 || j == g.y-1 || i == 0 || i == g.z-1 ) {
                    *(t++) = b_d;
                }
                else{ // Interior distance
                    fscanf(vti, "%lf ", t++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Grid3D make_grid3D(int x, int y, int z){
    Grid3D g;
    g.x = x; g.y = y; g.z = z;

    return g;
}
```

The code works when I discard the openacc directives and run it with [1-8] processes, but when using the open acc compiler I get a cudaError.

`call to cuStreamSynchronize returned error 700: Illegal address during kernel execution`

MPI compilation:

```
mpicc -Wall -g -std=c99 -I/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/include -L/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/lib -lmpi test.c -o mpi_exec.out
```

OpenACC compilation:

```
pgcc -acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel -g -lm -I/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/include -L/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/lib -lmpi test.c -o oacc_exec.out
```

To run the executable you need to pass in an input vti file and the output filename.

```
mpirun -np <1-8> <executable> input.vti outputName
```

Link to the input file [input.vti](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Sh1CrE94jfUlBGT2o3Z0NQUG8/view?usp=sharing)

I want this code to be very flexible, i want to make it so that it can run on a single node with 1 GPU while running [1-8] processes and also on [1-8] nodes with each node having [1-2] GPUS. And I am not using CUDA MPS.

My specifications

```
GNU/Linux x86_64
NVIDIA GeForce GTX Titan CC: 3.5

pgcc 15.7-0 64-bit target on x86-64 Linux -tp sandybridge 
gcc (GCC) 4.8.1
```

Any help or suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**

```
** Compiling with OpenACC

`$ pgcc -fast -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel -   I/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/include -L/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/lib -lmpi rcrovella.c -o withacc
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 88)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 142)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 143)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 308)
fast_sweep:
    225, Generating copy(p[:1])
    228, Loop is parallelizable
    230, Loop is parallelizable
         Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
        228, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.y */
        230, #pragma acc loop gang, vector(128) /* blockIdx.x threadIdx.x */
solveEikonal:
    246, Generating acc routine seq
    262, Loop is parallelizable
    263, Loop carried dependence of m prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of m prevents vectorization
         Loop carried dependence of d prevents parallelization
         Loop carried backward dependence of d prevents vectorization
PGC/x86-64 Linux 15.7-0: compilation completed with warnings`

** Compiling without OpenACC
pgcc -I/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/include -L/cm/shared/apps/openmpi/gcc/64/1.8.5_wocuda/lib -lmpi rcrovella.c -o   noaccPGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant    expressions (rcrovella.c: 88)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 142)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 143)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (rcrovella.c: 308)
PGC/x86-64 Linux 15.7-0: compilation completed with warnings

** Running with OpenACC
$ mpirun -n 1 withacc ../my_test/input.vti withacc1
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
withacc1 file created

** Running without OpenACC
$ mpirun -n 1 noacc ../my_test/input.vti noacc1
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
noacc1 file created

** Compare
$ diff -q noacc1.txt withacc1.txt
Files noacc1.txt and withacc1.txt differ
```

Comment: I don't have much experience with OpenACC, but it sounds like you are sending the data to the wrong coprocessor. That is, when you're debugging it, I would look to confirm that each node is sending its data to its own appropriate coprocessor(s), and that each coprocessor correctly receives the right data.

Comment: I think you should provide a complete MCVE.  Note that SO [expects](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for questions seeking debugging help, that you to provide this *in the question itself*, not in an external repository.  You should also describe your setup a bit.  What mpi command are you using to invoke this?  Do you expect all of the ranks GPU codes to run on a single GPU?  What is the compute mode setting for that GPU?  Are you using cuda MPS ?

Comment: I will provide a complete MCVE for this post.

Comment: I have updated my post with a complete MCVE, my specifications and commands used for compiling and running the code. I have also included the link to the input file used by the code. Also in this version I couldn't get openacc to work at all however solution to this should help me a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Also in this version I couldn't get openacc to work at all however solution to this should help me a lot.

Here's what I've found:

1. When you use the managed memory facility:

   ```
   -ta=tesla:managed
   ```

   typically we don't include `data` directives or clauses in our code.  The idea is to let the cuda managed memory runtime manage data movement for us.  So I commented out what I thought were two "extraneous" data directives.
2. I don't believe your `parallel` accelerator directive is correctly formed.  My compiler (PGI 15.7) barks at me that the `independent` directive inside the parallel region is not correct:

   ```
   PGCC-S-0155-Illegal context(parallel) for independent  (t2.c: 228)
   ```

   changing the `#pragma acc parallel` to `#pragma acc kernels` is one possible workaround.
3. Your code spits out some compiler warnings around the use of `INFINITY`.  Since these are just warnings, I didn't bother to address them.
4. For some reason, I found that the compiler wasn't handling the `SweepInfo` structure (`s`) properly on entry into the accelerator region.  To work around this, I modified this:

   ```
   int x, y, z, i, j, k, index;
   #pragma acc parallel
   {
     #pragma acc loop independent
     for(x = xs; x <= xe; x++) {
       #pragma acc loop independent
       for(y = ys; y <= ye; y++) {
         z = level - (x+y);
         if(z > 0 && z <= NZ-2) {
           i = abs(z-s->zSweepOff);
           j = abs(y-s->ySweepOff);
           k = abs(x-s->xSweepOff);
   ```

   to this:

   ```
   int x, y, z, i, j, k, index;
   int xSO = s->xSweepOff;
   int ySO = s->ySweepOff;
   int zSO = s->zSweepOff;
   #pragma acc kernels
   {
     #pragma acc loop independent
     for(x = xs; x <= xe; x++) {
       #pragma acc loop independent
       for(y = ys; y <= ye; y++) {
         z = level - (x+y);
         if(z > 0 && z <= NZ-2) {
           i = abs(z-zSO);
           j = abs(y-ySO);
           k = abs(x-xSO);
   ```

   I'll probably chew on this some more.  I think there is either a limitation here I don't understand or else a compiler bug.

With the above changes, I was able to get your code to run to completion without any obvious issues.  Here is my modified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define min(a,b) (a > b) ? b : a
#define max(a,b) (a < b) ? b : a

#define NPES 8 // max number of PEs allowed
#define DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION   -1
#define DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE   INFINITY
#define DEFAULT_INTERIOR_DISTANCE 90000

typedef struct {
  int order;
  int firstLevel, lastLevel, level;
  int xDim, yDim, zDim;
  int xSweepOff, ySweepOff, zSweepOff;
  double dx, dy, dz;
} SweepInfo;

typedef struct {
  double   dx, dy, dz;
  int * location;
  double * distance;
} Phi;

typedef struct {
  int x, y, z;
} Grid3D;



void calc_dist_field( Phi * p, int totalNodes );
void write_to_file(double * dist);
static SweepInfo make_sweepInfo( Phi * p, int my_rank );
static void fast_sweep( Phi * p, SweepInfo * s );
static double solveEikonal(Phi * p, int index, int max_x, int max_y);
static void update_distance(Phi * p, int totalNodes);
static void set_distance_negative_inside(Phi * p, int totalNodes);
static void adjust_boundary( Phi * p );


// public method declarations
Grid3D make_grid3D(int x, int y, int z);
void vti_get_dimensions(FILE *vti, double *d);
void vti_get_data(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g);

// private method declarations
static void move_file_pointer(FILE *file_ptr, int lineNumber, int r);
static void get_location(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, Grid3D g);
static void get_distance(FILE *vti, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g);

static int npes;          // Number of PEs
static int my_rank;       // Rank of the PE
static char * fileName;
static char * outfileName;

static int NX, NY, NZ, totalNodes;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // MPI startup routine
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &npes);

  fileName    = argv[1];
  outfileName = argv[2];
  FILE *f = fopen(fileName, "r");

  double dims[6];
  vti_get_dimensions(f, dims);
  NX = dims[0] + 3;
  NY = dims[1] + 3;
  NZ = dims[2] + 3;

  totalNodes = NX * NY * NZ;
  Phi *p = (Phi *) malloc(sizeof(Phi));
  p->location = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * totalNodes);
  p->distance = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double) * totalNodes);

  p->dx = dims[3]; p->dy = dims[4]; p->dz = dims[5];

  vti_get_data( f, p->location, DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION,
                   p->distance, DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE,
                make_grid3D(NX, NY, NZ));


  update_distance(p, totalNodes);

  calc_dist_field(p, totalNodes);

  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}

void calc_dist_field( Phi * p, int totalNodes ) {

  int sweepNumber = my_rank + 1;
  double * tmp_dist;

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  if(my_rank == 0){
    tmp_dist = (double *) malloc( totalNodes * sizeof(double) );
  }

  // sn represents the sweep number
  for( int sn = sweepNumber; sn <= NPES; sn += npes) {
    SweepInfo s = make_sweepInfo(p, sn);

    printf("PE: [%d] - performing sweep number ..... [%d/%d]\n", my_rank, sn, NPES);

    fast_sweep(p, &s);

    printf("PE: [%d] - completed sweep number ...... [%d/%d]\n", my_rank, sn, NPES);

  }

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
//  #pragma acc update host(p->distance[0:totalNodes])
  MPI_Reduce(p->distance, tmp_dist, totalNodes, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_MIN, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

  if( my_rank == 0 ) {
    free( p->distance );
    p->distance = tmp_dist;
    set_distance_negative_inside(p, totalNodes);
    adjust_boundary(p);
    write_to_file(p->distance);
    printf("%s file created\n", outfileName);
  }

}

static void update_distance(Phi * p, int totalNodes) {

  int    *l = &p->location[0];
  double *d = &p->distance[0];

  for(int i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    if(*l != DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION && *d != DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE ) {
      *d = (*l == 1 && *d == INFINITY) ? -1 : (*d > 0.0 || *d < 0.0) ? *d : DEFAULT_INTERIOR_DISTANCE;
    }
    l++; d++;
  }

}



void write_to_file(double * dist) {

  int x = NX;
  int y = NY;
  int z = NZ;
  char fname[255];
  sprintf(fname, "%s.txt", outfileName);
  FILE *fp = fopen(fname, "w");

  int i,j,k;
  double *t = &dist[0];
  for(i = 0; i < z; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < x; k++) {
    fprintf(fp, "%f  ", *(t++));
      }
      fprintf(fp, "\n");
    }
    fprintf(fp, "\n");
  }

}


static SweepInfo make_sweepInfo( Phi * p, int my_rank ) {
  SweepInfo s;

  s.order      = my_rank;
  s.firstLevel = 3;
  s.lastLevel  = (NX + NY + NZ) - 6;

  s.xDim = NX-2; s.dx = p->dx;
  s.yDim = NY-2; s.dy = p->dy;
  s.zDim = NZ-2; s.dz = p->dz;

  s.xSweepOff = (s.order == 4 || s.order == 8 ) ? s.xDim + 1 : 0;
  s.ySweepOff = (s.order == 2 || s.order == 6 ) ? s.yDim + 1 : 0;
  s.zSweepOff = (s.order == 3 || s.order == 7 ) ? s.zDim + 1 : 0;

  return s;
}

static void fast_sweep( Phi * p, SweepInfo * s ) {

  int start, end, incr;

  start = ( s->order == 2 || s->order == 5 || s->order == 7 || s->order == 8 ) ? s->lastLevel : s->firstLevel;

  if ( start == s->firstLevel ) {
    end  = s->lastLevel + 1;
    incr = 1;
  }
  else {
    end  = s->firstLevel - 1;
    incr = 0;
  }

  int max_x  = s->xDim + 2;
  int max_y  = s->yDim + 2;
  int max_xy = max_x * max_y;

  //#pragma acc data create(p[0:1]) copy(p->distance[0:totalNodes])
  for(int level = start; level != end; level = (incr) ? level+1 : level-1) {
    // s - start, e - end
    int xs, xe, ys, ye;

    xs = max(1, level-(s->yDim + s->zDim))    , ys = max(1,level-(s->xDim + s->zDim));
    xe = min(s->xDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1)), ye = min(s->yDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1));

    int x, y, z, i, j, k, index;
    int xSO = s->xSweepOff;
    int ySO = s->ySweepOff;
    int zSO = s->zSweepOff;
    #pragma acc kernels
    {
      #pragma acc loop independent
      for(x = xs; x <= xe; x++) {
        #pragma acc loop independent
        for(y = ys; y <= ye; y++) {
          z = level - (x+y);
          if(z > 0 && z <= NZ-2) {
            i = abs(z-zSO);
            j = abs(y-ySO);
            k = abs(x-xSO);
            index = i * max_xy + j * max_x + k;
            p->distance[index] = solveEikonal(p, index, NX, NY);
          }
        }
      } // end of acc parallel
    }
  }
}

#pragma acc routine seq
static double solveEikonal(Phi * p, int index, int max_x, int max_y) {

  int max_xy = max_x * max_y;

  double dist_new = 0;
  double dist_old = p->distance[index];

  double dx = p->dx, dy = p->dy, dz = p->dz;
  double minX = min(p->distance[index-1], p->distance[index+1]);
  double minY = min(p->distance[abs(index-max_x)], p->distance[abs(index+max_x)]);
  double minZ = min(p->distance[abs(index-max_xy)],p->distance[abs(index+max_xy)]);

  double m[] = { minX, minY, minZ} ;
  double d[] = { dx, dy, dz};

  // sort the mins 
  for(int i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 3-i; j++) {
      if(m[j] > m[j+1]) {
        double tmp_m = m[j];
        double tmp_d = d[j];
        m[j] = m[j+1]; d[j] = d[j+1];
        m[j+1] = tmp_m; d[j+1] = tmp_d;
      }
    }
  }

  // simplifying the variables
  double m_0 = m[0], m_1 = m[1], m_2 = m[2];
  double d_0 = d[0], d_1 = d[1], d_2 = d[2]; 
  double m2_0 = m_0 * m_0, m2_1 = m_1 * m_1, m2_2 = m_2 * m_2;
  double d2_0 = d_0 * d_0, d2_1 = d_1 * d_1, d2_2 = d_2 * d_2;

  dist_new = m_0 + d_0;
  if(dist_new > m_1) {

    double s = sqrt(- m2_0 + 2 * m_0 * m_1 - m2_1 + d2_0 + d2_1); 
    dist_new = ( m_1 * d2_0 + m_0 * d2_1 + d_0 * d_1 * s) / (d2_0 + d2_1);

    if(dist_new > m_2) {

      double a = sqrt(- m2_0 * d2_1 - m2_0 * d2_2 + 2 * m_0 * m_1 * d2_2
                      - m2_1 * d2_0 - m2_1 * d2_2 + 2 * m_0 * m_2 * d2_1
                      - m2_2 * d2_0 - m2_2 * d2_1 + 2 * m_1 * m_2 * d2_0
                      + d2_0 * d2_1 + d2_0 * d2_2 + d2_1 * d2_2);

      dist_new = (m_2 * d2_0 * d2_1 + m_1 * d2_0 * d2_2 + m_0 * d2_1 * d2_2 + d_0 * d_1 * d_2 * a) /
                  (d2_0 * d2_1 + d2_0 * d2_2 + d2_1 * d2_2);
    }
  }

  return min(dist_old, dist_new);
}



static void set_distance_negative_inside(Phi * p, int totalNodes) {

  int    *l = &p->location[0];
  double *d = &p->distance[0];

  for(int i = 0; i < totalNodes; i++) {
    if(*l != DEFAULT_BORDER_LOCATION && *d != DEFAULT_BORDER_DISTANCE ) {
      if( *l == 1) *d = -1;
    }
    l++; d++;
  }

}

static void adjust_boundary( Phi * p ) {

  int x, y, z, xy, i, j, k;
  x  = NX;
  y  = NY;
  z  = NZ;
  xy = x * y;

  for(i = 0; i < z; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < y; j++){
      for(k = 0; k < x; k++){
        int I = i, J = j, K = k;
        I = (i == z-1) ? I-1 : (!i) ? I+1 : I;
        J = (j == y-1) ? J-1 : (!j) ? J+1 : J;
        K = (k == x-1) ? K-1 : (!k) ? K+1 : K;
        if( i != I || j != J || k != K) {
            int l_index = i * xy + j * x + k;
            int r_index = I * xy + J * x + K;
            p->distance[l_index] = p->distance[r_index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}



/**************** vti_parser ********************************/

static void move_file_pointer(FILE *file_ptr, int lineNumber, int r) {
    char tmpStr[512];
    if(r) rewind(file_ptr);
    while (lineNumber > 0){
        fgets (tmpStr, 511, file_ptr);
        lineNumber--;
    }
}

void vti_get_dimensions(FILE *vti, double *d) {
    char tmpStr[512];
    rewind(vti);
    while (1) {
        fgets (tmpStr, 511, vti);
        if ( strstr(tmpStr, "ImageData WholeExtent") ) {
            sscanf(tmpStr, "    <ImageData WholeExtent=\"0 %lf 0 %lf 0 %lf\" Spacing=\"%lf %lf %lf\">",
                    &d[0], &d[1], &d[2], &d[3], &d[4], &d[5]);
            break;
        }
    }
}


void vti_get_data(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g) {

    // move the file pointer to
    // line 6 from beginning
    move_file_pointer(vti, 6, 1);

    get_location(vti, l, b_l, g);

    // move the file pointer 2 lines
    // forward from its last position
    move_file_pointer(vti, 2, 0);

    get_distance(vti, d, b_d, g);

}

static void get_location(FILE *vti, int *l, int b_l, Grid3D g) {
    int i, j, k, *t = &l[0];
    for (i = 0; i < g.z; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < g.y; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < g.x; k++) {
                // Border
                if (k == 0 || k == g.x-1 || j == 0 || j == g.y-1 || i == 0 || i == g.z-1 ) {
                    *(t++) = b_l;
                }
                else{ // Interior
                    fscanf(vti, "%d ", t++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



static void get_distance(FILE *vti, double *d, double b_d, Grid3D g) {
    int i, j, k;
    double *t = &d[0];
    for (i = 0; i < g.z; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < g.y; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < g.x; k++) {
                // Border distance
                if (k == 0 || k == g.x-1 || j == 0 || j == g.y-1 || i == 0 || i == g.z-1 ) {
                    *(t++) = b_d;
                }
                else{ // Interior distance
                    fscanf(vti, "%lf ", t++);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Grid3D make_grid3D(int x, int y, int z){
    Grid3D g;
    g.x = x; g.y = y; g.z = z;

    return g;
}
```

Here is my compile command:

```
pgc++ -fast -acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel -I/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/include -L/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/lib -lmpi t2.c -o t2
```

And this is the output:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/lib ./t2 input.vti output
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
output file created
$
```

In my case, it seemed to run faster than the non-OpenACC version (compile without `-acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel`) and I `diff`-ed the output files created and they were the same between non-OpenACC and OpenACC versions.

I also tried running this code with 2 MPI ranks.  It seemed to run without crashing:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/lib /opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun -n 2 ./t2 input.vti output
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
output file created
$
```

The output data file was different from the single rank version, but it matched the version produced by a two-rank non-OpenACC run.  So if there are any remaining issues, I think they are MPI related and not OpenACC related.

**EDIT:**

To exand on this last point, let's take OpenACC out of the picture, but just use the MPI (MPICH) that comes with the PGI 15.7 toolchain:

```
$ /opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/bin/mpicc t2.c -o t2 -lmpi
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (t2.c: 88)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (t2.c: 142)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (t2.c: 143)
PGC-W-0129-Floating point overflow. Check constants and constant expressions (t2.c: 308)
PGC/x86-64 Linux 15.7-0: compilation completed with warnings
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/lib /opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun -n 1 ./t2 input.vti output1rank
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
output1rank file created
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/lib /opt/pgi/linux86-64/15.7/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun -n 2 ./t2 input.vti output2rank
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [1/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [2/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [2/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [4/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [1/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [3/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [4/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [6/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [3/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [5/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [6/8]
PE: [1] - performing sweep number ..... [8/8]
PE: [1] - completed sweep number ...... [8/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [5/8]
PE: [0] - performing sweep number ..... [7/8]
PE: [0] - completed sweep number ...... [7/8]
output2rank file created
$ diff -q output1rank.txt output2rank.txt
Files output1rank.txt and output2rank.txt differ
$
```

Comment: For some reason it looks like the non-OpenACC version (compile without -acc) still compiles an accelerated code and therefore the output matches the OpenACC version (compile with -acc). The output produced by compiling the code with `mpicc` and running with [1-8] ranks all produce the same and correct result. But the output produced by OpenACC (with and without -acc) produces incorrect results. Although I am using `pgcc` compiler instead of `pgc++` which shouldn't make a difference. Could you check the diff between the output from `mpicc` and `openacc`.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear when I said the non-OpenACC version.  I am compiling without `-acc -ta=tesla:managed -Minfo=accel`.  That will definitely produce a version that does not use OpenACC, and that version matches the data produced by the OpenACC version.

Comment: If I run the OpenACC version of the  code in my answer with a single mpi rank (mpirun -n 1) it matches the output from the non-ACC case and the openACC case without MPI.  If I run the non-OpenACC version with a single MPI rank, and compare the non-OpenACC version with 2 MPI ranks, the outputs don't match.  I think the issue is in how this code is structured to use MPI, not in how it is using OpenACC.  The OpenACC results are always consistent with the non-OpenACC results, for every case I've tried.

Comment: I've updated my answer at the end to show the full terminal session of compiling the code in my answer without OpenACC (using mpicc and the PGI toolchain) and running a 1-rank run and a 2-rank run.  Using this code and this toolchain, the MPI 1-rank and 2-rank results do  not match.  This has nothing to do with OpenACC. Furthermore, although I haven't shown it, the MPI 1 rank run **with** OpenACC output matches the MPI 1 rank run **without** OpenACC output, and the MPI 2-rank run **with** OpenACC output  matches the MPI 2-rank run **without** OpenACC.

Comment: I see what you are saying the results are a little different with different MPI ranks. But I am not getting same results for single rank openACC and nonOpenACC case and I am so confused to why that is the.

Comment: Apparently the results differ between `pgcc` and `pgc++`  I'm not sure why yet.  Can you try switching to pgc++ to see if your non-ACC and ACC results match in that case?

Comment: I get compilation errors using `pgc++`. It does not like the `mpi` libraries and i am not sure if I need to have `c++` `mpi` libraries to use it with `pgc++`

Comment: I was able to compile the code with `pgc++` compiler and the results are same for the non-ACC and ACC versions. I am not sure if it makes sense for the different results between `pgcc` and `pgc++` but this should solve my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that this could a bug in pgcc (but not in pgc++).

After some experiments, I came to the conclusion that the numbers of iterations of the x and y loops are probably computed incorrectly probably because the compiler is attempting an illegal optimization (or a stack corruption?).

I was able to get a proper result with 'pgcc -acc' after applying the following transformation to the code given in the 1st Answer.

```
xs = max(1, level-(s->yDim + s->zDim))    , ys = max(1,level-(s->xDim + s->zDim));
xe = min(s->xDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1)), ye = min(s->yDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1));
---->
if (level != 99999) {
 xs = max(1, level-(s->yDim + s->zDim))    , ys = max(1,level-(s->xDim + s->zDim));
 xe = min(s->xDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1)), ye = min(s->yDim, level-(s->firstLevel-1));
}
```

The additional IF is of course always TRUE but the compiler has no ways to know that so this is enough to prevent most optimization attempts.

PS: I also recommend to replace the comma between the assignments by a semi-column. The comma has higher precedence than the assignment so this is not wrong but just a bit disturbing.

Comment: Also, be careful with the min() and max() macros. Without proper () it is easy to get hit by a nasty precedence bug. #define min(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(b):(a))

Comment: Thank you @Stephane for looking into this and finding a solution for me to work with `pgcc`. I think for now I will stick to `pgc++` but will take your suggestions into consideration and refactor my code.